# error in running mysql script

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a mysql script which comes from some other pc , where it was running fine 
the same thing when i run on my machine 
it gives error

please see this screenshot

one of the error is on date if i use this date '1970-01-01 00:00:00'  it gives error 
if I use this date '2000-01-01 00:00:00'

It starts working ..

Any idea what could be the reason

script:

```
  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `dashboard2`;
  CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dashboard2` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
  USE `dashboard2`;
```

-- Dumping structure for table dashboard2.dmpfiles
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dmpfiles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dmpfiles` (
  `dbid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sig` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `eventid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `occurred` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 05:30:01',
  `version` varchar(25) DEFAULT '0',
  `stringid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `lastadj` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 05:30:01',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dbid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Dumping data for table dashboard2.dmpfiles: ~1 rows (approximately)
    DELETE FROM `dmpfiles`;
   /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `dmpfiles` DISABLE KEYS */;
   INSERT INTO `dmpfiles` (`dbid`, `sig`, `eventid`, `occurred`, `version`, `stringid`, `lastadj`)     VALUES
    (1, 'Scanner version (2.3.0 6/4/2014)', 1, '2014-06-13 14:25:31', '2.3.0', 0, '2014-10-20 17:52:00');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `dmpfiles` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping structure for table dashboard2.properties
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `properties`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `properties` (
  `pid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Dumping data for table dashboard2.properties: ~24 rows (approximately)
DELETE FROM `properties`;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `properties` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `properties` (`pid`, `type`, `name`, `id`, `value`) VALUES
    (1, 'db', 'DbVersion', '0', '3'),
    (2, 'system', 'timezone', '0', 'America/New_York'),
    (3, 'system', 'classname', '6', 'new ip'),
    (4, 'system', 'classname', '17', 'mac move'),
    (5, 'system', 'classname', '19', 'mac change'),
    (6, 'system', 'classname', '20', 'ip change'),
    (7, 'system', 'classname', '30', 'admin move'),
    (8, 'system', 'classname', '35', 'speed'),
    (9, 'system', 'classname', '101', 'ping over'),
    (10, 'system', 'classname', '102', 'bw over'),
    (11, 'system', 'classname', '103', 'new ip'),
    (12, 'system', 'classname', '104', 'move'),
    (13, 'system', 'classname', '107', 'name change'),
    (14, 'system', 'classname', '108', 'speed2'),
    (15, 'system', 'classname', '109', 'ENETIP change'),
    (16, 'system', 'classname', '0', 'reserved'),
    (17, 'system', 'classname', '0', 'reserved'),
    (18, 'system', 'classname', '0', 'reserved'),
    (19, 'system', 'classname', '0', 'reserved'),
    (20, 'system', 'classname', '0', 'reserved'),
    (21, 'system', 'classname', '0', 'reserved'),
    (22, 'system', 'classname', '0', 'reserved'),
    (23, 'db', 'current.db', '0', '1'),
    (24, 'System', 'tzoffset', '0', '-14400000');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `properties` ENABLE KEYS */;

[image]

Comment: Forgive me my tone, I'm just going to assume you already did everything possible to figure out what `Table dasboard.... doesn't exist` could mean, right? Besides that, you only show a very limited amount of the script and error messages.

Comment: updated screenshot , I am concerning on the first 2/3 lines ..like invalid value for occured  ..dashboard.dmpfiles doesnt exist.. these errors are not coming on the other machine

Comment: @junaidp: Is it really hard to copy the code and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC.

It will never take default value as '1970-01-01 00:00:00'` for timestamp data type as its out of the range.

Comment: beacuse of timezone issue its mentioned as UTC and could be possible your mysqldd having different timezone and you add 05:30Hrs in above time. I think just try first this `1970-01-01 05:30:01`

Comment: For more information you can execute the query `SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP();` and check that what is time difference with your local time as well you can also visit the website http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36214

Comment: this date works , but other issues remains there , as you see in the screenshot the next error, its not inserting values..I thought there will some general issue in my sql setting or something , because all errors only coming in this machine